# .NET getting a ThreadStateException

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

Hello I am getting an error on the following line:

```
If Not System.Windows.Clipboard.GetDataObject Is Nothing Then
```

I believe it would look something like this in C#

```
if (System.Windows.Clipboard.GetDataObject!=null) {
```

The Error is:

"ThreadStateException: Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made."

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? A few suggestions online mentioned adding `<STAThread()> _` over the 'main' method, however, this is an ASP.NET controller method, I tried adding this over it and it didn't help. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET doesn't really get along with STAThread.

You need an additional task scheduler to run a thread in STA mode to access what you want from the operating system

Take a look at [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/07/9990421.aspx) it got me going with something like this.

Also, keep in mind that multiple request to your page might mess up things, since you're interacting with the clipboard of the operating system (which runs in another COM context) son concurrency might by risky.

What are you trying to acomplish, maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Trying to convert an incoming Word document to an image, pretty much I did 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document.Selection.CopyAsPicture' and now trying to get the picture. Based on your explanation thought it is probably no a good idea the way I am doing it. Any suggestions?

Comment: There are products that can do that, a pdf printer sounds like a good idea too. But office automation in ASP.NET applications is unsupported (tried to do the same thing with infopath)

Comment: For Word functionality checkout the Aspose suit. Amyuni is a good PDF Printer. Both are paid but worth it

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to read the final notes.

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/community-forums/interesting-resources/using-clipboard-class-in-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this can be caused by an out of date dll in your /bin directory. Have you tried clearing it?

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/2411f889-8e30-4a6d-9e28-8a46e66c0fdb/

http://www.devnewsgroups.net/windowsforms/t36723-current-thread-must-set-single-thread-apartment-sta.aspx

Also, you can explicitly start up a new thread in Single Apartment Mode

```vb
imports System.Threading

 dim newThread As New Thread(new ThreadStart(AddressOf ThreadMethod))
 newThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
 newThread.Start();

 'and elsewhere
 Public Sub ThreadMethod()
     If Not System.Windows.Clipboard.GetDataObject Is Nothing Then
        'stuff
     End if
 End Sub
```

Comment: I tried doing `Dim wordThread As Thread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(CreateWordPreview(br, streamLength, key + fileName)))` But I get a compile error: 'Delegate 'System.Threading.ThreadStart' requires an 'AddressOf' expression or lambda expression as the only argument to its constructor.

Comment: Oops. A little mistake for converting from C# to VB.Net: there needs to be an AddressOf before "ThreadMethod" (changed my answer)